# kafka broker, producer and consumer related

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible to run producer on different system and consumer on different system and still consumer receives all the topics which are being produced by the producer?

Answer (score 0):

The central idea of a distributed platform is to have different components in different machines/hardware/datacenter. There are 3 components Zookeeper/Kafka broker or server, message Producer, message consumer.
These 3 can be on same machine or different machines, so far as Producers and Consumers can connect to kafka bootstrap. They need not be in the same physical data center just being able to communicate with kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Your clients simply connect to the Kafka broker over TCP and send/receive messages regardless of the machine on which they're running. You just need to make sure that the networking is set up correctly (i.e. the machines can reach the appropriate ports on each other).